# Проблема в компиляции скрипта python

Tags: python

У меня есть скрипт (полностью рабочий). Я пытаюсь установить библиотеку auto-py-to-exe (она установилась), когда я хочу запустить библиотеку и ввожу python -m auto-py-to-exe, то python выдаёт ошибку, что такой библиотеки нет. Как это можно исправить?
UPD: я пробовал устанавливать через git

Comment: Ну как минимум сразу можно сказать, что в именах модулей в принципе не может быть дефисов и такая команда в принципе никогда не заработает, а ещё можно сразу сказать, что вы не читали документацию по auto-py-to-exe, потому что в ней есть примеры правильных команд

Comment: @andreymal Не в этом дело, я пробовал и pyinstaller, и py2exe, ничего питон не хочет находить